# Firestore: Search/filter functionality over multiple fields in nested Maps/arrays by logical OR

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have to implement a filter + search functionality in an Android app (for a university course).
The app lists food companies and makes them searchable. The database we have to use is Firestore.

The filter + search mechanism I have to implement looks like this:

1. Get all documents which fulfill the filter settings.
2. Of those documents do an OR query over multiple fields to compare field values with strings of the search bar.

Unfortunately, this seems to be a really complex task in Firestore.
I am well aware of all the other questions asking only for parts of my problem (how to do logical OR queries, how to search over multiple fields etc.). But I struggle since two days to build a working implementation from those solutions.

The document for one *company* looks like this (simplified):

```
String name
String description
String[] types       -> ["shop", "producer", "restaurant", ...]
Map[] openingHours   -> Map[] Monday  -> [begin, end]
                     -> Map[] Tuesday -> [begin, end]
                     ...
Map[] productGroups  -> String category
                        Boolean rawProduct
                        String[] seasons
                        String[] tags
                        ...
                     -> String category
                        Boolean rawProduct
                        String[] seasons
                        String[] tags
                        ...
```

The problems which I have to solve in combination are:

*Problem 1*: How to filter for `productGroups->category`, afterwards for `rawProduct` and after that for `seasons` for *each* product of *each* company?

*Problem 2*: How would an AND query for problem 1 look like, if `array-contains` can only be used once in a query? Creating new fields for all kinds of filter combinations and search them seems overkill (I have to filter for 20+ fields).

*Problem 3*: How to build from all those "problem-2"-queries logical OR queries, to compare string values in multiple fields like `name`, `description`, `types[]` and `productGroups[]->tags[]`?

Could someone give me a hint how to break down this problem into simpler queries without getting lost?

Comment: So I finally have a half working implementation. Will post it as an answer once all bugs are fixed.

Comment: Once you have a fully working implementation, it will greatly increase the visibility to other users if you post the solution as an answer and you accept it. Thank you in advance!